# Caliburn Micro unsubscribe message type from event aggregator

Tags: caliburn.micro

I like the Event Aggregator but run into the situation where I subscribe to and publish the same same message.  This potentially makes the code run twice.  I thought I could make an easy extension method to unsubscribe from the message, publish, and then subscribe to the message.

Is this possible or is there a better pattern (maybe use a GUID for each message to ignore handling a message you sent)?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to pass the sender in the message and ensure to have received it in a different instance before performing the action.